# How can I change the position of a tab on product page Magento 2

Tags: magento2

https://www.cloudways.com/blog/add-custom-tab-product-page-magento-2/

Here we can see an example of how to add a new custom tab to a product page. I'd like to know how we can sort positions for tabs.

Comment: are you referring to custom tab??
you can set priority or sort on tabs to change their position `<argument name="priority" xsi:type="string">50</argument>`

Comment: I found this answer about my question: https://outlandweb.zendesk.com/hc/nl/articles/115000346869-Change-order-of-tabs-on-product-page I hope it helps you too!